# Discard values not followed by specific character

Tags: python

In the following string

`1902  -646E     -23E     179E     897E    1430E    1930E    1967E    1999E   -9999      849E      20E    -678E1`

I want the program to discard all numbers which are not directly followed by the letter E. How can I do this with re?

Comment: How are the numbers seperated, is it space or tab between them?

Comment: Never mind, I just did it myself.